# How to hide toolbar when scrolling while also excluding bottom banner adview from this behavior?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library

My main activity has toolbar and tablayout under it. And the recyclerview content under them is created by a fragment. I want to hide the toolbar and tablayout when scrolling to open up space. So I've added `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to their xml. But the problem is I've banner adview at the bottom of the fragment and when I apply this scrolling behaviour, the banner is also showing the same behaviour. It is hidden when fragment is created and appears only when scrolled up and disappears when scrolled down. I want to exclude banner adview from this behaviour and keep it fixed at the bottom. I've looked at other questions but couldn't find an answer.

**This is my Main Activity xml:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white">

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**This is the fragment's xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bannerAdView">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_tops"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_top_fragment"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bannerAdView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"  only

Comment: Thanks, I will try but i want the toolbar to re-appear  when scrolled down since there are menu items that may needed.